# jSon_encode like function for Delphi which accepts TDataSet

Tags: delphi

I have been tasked with creating a Indy server in Delphi 2007 which communicates with clients and returns json formatted data from Sql based databases.  Someone from our office created a prototype using php.  And in the prototype they use the **jSon_encode** function extensively to return the data from tables.  I was wondering if there was a similar Delphi function which could accept a **TDataSet** parameter and return properly formatted json data.

Anyone know of such function?

**Update 12/10/2013** - my modification to @user2748835 answer:

```
function jsonencode(mString: String): String;
begin
  result := StringReplace(mString,'''','\''',[rfReplaceAll,rfIgnoreCase]);
  result := StringReplace(mString,'\','\\',[rfReplaceAll,rfIgnoreCase]);
  result := StringReplace(result,crlf,'\n',[rfReplaceAll,rfIgnoreCase]);
  result := StringReplace(result,'"','\"',[rfReplaceAll,rfIgnoreCase]);
  result := StringReplace(result,'/','\/',[rfReplaceAll,rfIgnoreCase]);
  result := StringReplace(result,'#9','\t',[rfReplaceAll,rfIgnoreCase]);
end;

function jSon_encode(aDataset:TDataset):string;
  function fieldToJSON(thisField:TField):string;
  begin
    try
      result := '"'+thisField.fieldName+'":';
      case thisField.DataType of
        ftInteger,ftSmallint,ftLargeint:
          result := result+inttostr(thisField.AsInteger);
        ftDateTime:
          result := result+'"'+formatdatetime('YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS',thisField.AsDateTime)+'"';
        ftCurrency,
        ftFloat:
          result := result + floattostr(thisField.AsFloat);
        ftString :
          result := result + '"'+jsonencode(thisField.AsString)+'"';
        else
      end; // case
      result := result + ','; 
    except
      on e: Exception do begin
        appendtolog('problem escaping field '+thisfield.fieldname);
      end;
    end;

  end; // of fieldToJSON

  function rowToJSON(ds:TDataset):string;
  var
    fieldIx : integer;
  begin
    result := '';
    for fieldIx := 0 to ds.fieldcount-1 do
      result := result + fieldToJSON(ds.Fields[fieldIx]);
    // trim comma after last col
    result := '{'+copy(result,1,length(result)-1)+'},';
  end; // of rowToJSON
begin
  result := '';
  with aDataset do
  begin
    if not bof then first;
    while not eof do
    begin
      result := result + rowToJSON(aDataset);
      next;
    end;
  end;
  //strip last comma and add
  if length(result)>0 then
    result := copy(result,1,length(result)-1);
  result := '['+result+']';
end; // of DSToJSON
```

Comment: May I ask, why it has to be that specific combination: JSON + TDataSet + Indy? Does PHP support TDataSet and is only able to talk to Indy servers via JSON? Or could it be any protocol over any transport, using a customizable RPC service/client combination?

Comment: You can build this function in about 10 minutes. Thats developers life - building functions they need

Comment: @JensG - Perhaps I was not clear.  I am essentially porting php to Delphi.  And was inquiring if there was a function which would take a TDataSet with basic field types (integer, char, real, etc) and generate a properly formatted json steam.

Comment: That sheds some light. I did read it as "I want to connect PHP and Delphi using JSON and sockets", hence the question, why TDataSet. PS: Your encoding function has a few flaws. First, it will never detect standalone `#13` and `#10` and leave them unencoded (assuming your CRLF means the usual combination of `#13#10`). Second, any nonprintable char and/or unicode char will probably be not correctly encoded. Last, the input value `mString` is used incorrectly twice, instead of only once.

Comment: (4) the second replacement will encode all the backslashes from the first replacement again, after (3) above has been corrected. Always escape the escape char first. @SirRufo: That's why it is not always a good idea to invent the wheel over and over again.

Comment: @JensG I had a JSON library in mind (SuperObject, etc.). So there is no reinvented wheel - just a simple bridge :o)

Comment: I've been working on very similar things, and have been hand-writing all JSON serialization/parsing routines using SuperObject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a TDataset, you can loop through the Fields collection and construct the json output and then in the loop, check the fieldtype and encode the value accordingly.
Something like:

```
uses db;
function DSToJSON(aDataset:TDataset):string;
 function fieldToJSON(thisField:TField):string;
 begin
   result := '"'+thisField.fieldName+'":';
   case thisField.DataType of
   ftInteger,
   ftSmallint,
   ftCurrency,
   ftFloat,
   ftLargeInt:
      result := result+thisField.value+^n^j;
   ftString :
      result := noSingleQuotes(thisField.value)+^n^j;
   else
   end; // case
 end; // of fieldToJSON
  function rowToJSON(ds:TDataset):string;
  var
    fieldIx : integer;
  begin
    for fieldIx := 0 to ds.fieldcount-1 do
      result := result + fieldToJSON(ds.Fields[fieldIx]);
    // trim comma after last col
    result := '{'+copy(result,1,length(result)-1)+'},';
  end; // of rowToJSON
begin
  result := '';
  with aDataset do
  begin
    if not bof then first;
    while not eof do
    begin
      result := result + rowToJSON(aDataset);
      next;
    end;
  end;
  //strip last comma and add
  if length(result)>0 then
    result := copy(result,1,length(result)-1);
  result := '['+result+']';
end; // of DSToJSON
```

Comment: This is more or less it.  But I made some modifications.  see my "12/10/2013" note.

Answer (score 2):

We just added a more complete and faster function, in our Open Source repository.

It is part of our *mORMot* framework, but can be used as a stand-alone unit, not tied to other features.

See in [SynVirtualDataSet.pas](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SynVirtualDataset.pas):

```
function DataSetToJSON(Data: TDataSet): RawUTF8
```

See [this commit](http://synopse.info/fossil/info/3c2a6e082a) and the [associated forum thread](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=10041#p10041).

Answer (score 0):

You can change every row into object and use serializing http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Serializing_User_Objects